# Is there a way to orderby using a value from a different array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, sorting

Hey so i have one array with data like this

```
arr1 = [
{mood: "good", name: "Jake"},
{mood: "good", name: "Jill"},
{mood: "good", name: "Jack"}
]
```

and another array

```
arr2 = [
{number: 2, name: "Jake"},
{number: 1, name: "Jill"},
{number: 3, name: "Jack"}
]
```

I was looking to sort array one using the number from array 2. So, basically I would need to use a filter to match the name from arr1 to arr2 and then get the number from the resulting array and sort.

How can I get this done ?

```
arr1.sort((a: any, b: any) => arr1.filter((item: { name: string; }) => item.name == arr2[i].name));
```

I am totally lost, so much so, I may not have asked a proper question !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use an object for the order of name and take the value for sorting.

```js
const
    arr1 = [{ mood: "good", name: "Jake" }, { mood: "good", name: "Jill" }, { mood: "good", name: "Jack" }],
    arr2 = [{ number: 2, name: "Jake" }, { number: 1, name: "Jill" }, { number: 3, name: "Jack" }],
    order = Object.fromEntries(arr2.map(({ name, number }) => [name, number]));

arr1.sort((a, b) => order[a.name] - order[b.name]);

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Sorting by index. `arr2` has a different order than above.

```js
const
    arr1 = [{ mood: "good", name: "Jake" }, { mood: "good", name: "Jill" }, { mood: "good", name: "Jack" }],
    arr2 = [{ number: 1, name: "Jill" }, { number: 2, name: "Jake" }, { number: 3, name: "Jack" }],
    order = Object.fromEntries(arr2.map(({ name }, index) => [name, index + 1]));

arr1.sort((a, b) => order[a.name] - order[b.name]);

console.log(arr1);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you Nina. Your solution works seamlessly.

Comment: Nina, lets say that **Number** is not present in **arr2**, and the only order is that the objects are indexed in the correct order. How do i then use the index of the object to do the sorting ?

Comment: what should happen if no oder is known?

Comment: Not that the order is unknown. Just that the Number element is not present. But, the objects in arr2 is already ordered. So I  would like to use the index of the objects instead of the Number element in the objects.

Comment: the index is not handed over to the sorting callback. if you need a default, you need to store it first in the array or take a week map with the objects and their index. btw, what should happen if one object has an oder and the other has an index?

Comment: They won't it's either or. I have been having a difficult time getting this correct. In the code you provided all I would do is change `arr2.map` to `arr2.weakmap(add a filter to find index of odject containing name)`

Comment: can you please alter the code to reflect that ?

Comment: i still have a problem with the data. do you have some data with unknown order and the wanted result of it?

Comment: Yes `arr1` has unknown order. While `arr2` is in the correct order. In an actual use case the elements contained in objects from both arrays are different, but for the **Name**. So ideally I would like to reorder **arr1** as **arr2**, using the **Name** element that is contained in both as the link between the two arrays.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256729/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-soobnaibot).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a lookup function to find the number, like this:

```js
const arr1 = [{"mood":"good","name":"Jake"},{"mood":"good","name":"Jill"},{"mood":"good","name":"Jack"}]
const arr2 = [{"number":2,"name":"Jake"},{"number":1,"name":"Jill"},{"number":3,"name":"Jack"}]

const f = ({name: a}) => arr2.find(({name: b}) => a === b).number

arr1.sort((a, b) => f(a) - f(b))

console.log(arr1)
```

If you want to improve performance, you can use a cache, like this:

```js
const arr1 = [{"mood":"good","name":"Jake"},{"mood":"good","name":"Jill"},{"mood":"good","name":"Jack"}]
const arr2 = [{"number":2,"name":"Jake"},{"number":1,"name":"Jill"},{"number":3,"name":"Jack"}]

const cache = {}
const f = ({name: a}) => cache[a] ??= arr2.find(({name: b}) => a===b).number

arr1.sort((a, b) => f(a) - f(b))

console.log(arr1)
```

Comment: You could improve the efficiency by either enriching the `arr1` with the `number`, or create an temp object with `{[name]: number}` and reference that from inside `sort`.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli good point, I've added a cached version

Comment: this works on here but when I add this to my use case it breaks the file. Console says `arr2.find(({name: b}) => a === b).number` is undefined